# Memory allocation in Javascript when consuming a serialized value from Rust

Tags: rust, serde, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

Using prost I build this serialized type for my `SecretKey`

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(default, rename_all = "camelCase")]
#[allow(clippy::derive_partial_eq_without_eq)]
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Message)]
pub struct SecretKey {
    #[prost(bytes = "vec", tag = "1")]
    pub coefficients: ::prost::alloc::vec::Vec<u8>,
}
```

In order to consume that inside a web app function, I declare the following function

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn state0_bindgen() -> JsValue {

    let secret_key = state0();

    serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&secret_key).unwrap()
}
```

Here's [a guide](https://docs.rs/serde-wasm-bindgen/latest/serde_wasm_bindgen/) that explains how types are converted from Rust to JS using `serde_wasm_bindgen`.

`wasm-pack` allows me to compile this function to wasm (using web as target) and eventually consume it inside a HTML file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>mp-psi example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import init, { state0_bindgen } from "./mp_psi.js";

      init().then(() => {
        const sk = state0_bindgen();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I'm trying to benchmark how much memory is allocated for the serialized `sk` array in Javascript. The rust type of `coefficients` is `Vec<u8>`. Is it being serialized as a `Uint8Array`? Can you help me determine how much memory is allocated to this array?